# How to make a rotating linearly polarized (not circular polarization) beam from a single beam?

Tags: optics

One way to make a linearly polarized beam rotating at frequency $\Delta f\approx10\mbox{MHz}$ is by combining two circularly polarized beams, one left-handed and one right-handed, and where one beam is at a frequency $f$ and the other at $f\pm\Delta f$. Is there another way to do this using only a single beam passed through some active optical device (eg electro-optic-modulator)? I'm interested in the mid-infrared (10.6um).

Comment: Just put a polarizing filter there and rotate it with an electric motor, if you don't need very high rotation frequency that would do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately I would need frequency of about 10MHz. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Faraday Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect). The plane of polarization in a medium is rotated when exposed to a magnetic field. Solenoid, glass rod.

Answer (score 1):

A Pockel cell followed by a quarter waveplate will do this. The Pockel cell acts as an electrically controlled waveplate which will give an elliptical state. The waveplate will then convert this to a rotated linear state. Producing a 10MHz driving signal at the several kilovolts required might be a challenge but not impossible.